# Did mimeType-check got broken in Android 7.0 Nougat? (intent-filter of android manifest)

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-7.0-nougat

It seems android's **My Files** app doesn't work well with the following `AndroidManifest.xml` configuration:

```
  <intent-filter>
     <data android:scheme="file" />
     <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.myext" />
     ...
```

Some online sources recommend using

```
  <intent-filter>
     <data android:scheme="content" />
     <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
     ...
```

This means that your app will be trying to open all binary files. Which is not ideal, but fine, as long as it works...

Well, surprise surprise it stops working when you install the latest Android updates and update to `7.0 Nougat`.

To solve this issue I tried using:

```
  <intent-filter>
     <data android:scheme="content" />
     <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
     ...
```

and see that the mime type is empty. ***So it seems that Nougat version not only scrambles the original URL, and hides its extension, but it also loses the mime type?!***

***Has anyone seen any working examples of custom file extensions (file extension association) on `Android 7.0 Nougat`? How can I configure the android manifest XML? Which targetSdkVersion should I use?***

Comment: I think the problem might be somewhere else, using `*/*` mean you can use any types e.g using `text/*` mean you set type for all text types.

Comment: When did android intent filter work with file extensions?

Comment: Did you make sure to include category default in your filters?

Comment: "When did android intent filter work with file extensions" 
<- Actually it works fine with "ES File Explorer" app, but not with "My Files" app.

Comment: "Did you make sure to include category default in your filters?" <- Yes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this part](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#sharing-files) of the Android Nougat changes document, they did make the following changes to the way files are to be shared :-

> For apps targeting Android 7.0, the Android framework enforces the StrictMode API policy that prohibits exposing file:// URIs outside
>   your app. If an intent containing a file URI leaves your app, the app
>   fails with a FileUriExposedException exception.
>
> To share files between applications, you should send a content:// URI
>   and grant a temporary access permission on the URI. The easiest way to
>   grant this permission is by using the FileProvider class. For more
>   information on permissions and sharing files, see Sharing Files.

You've already mentioned all the required `intent-filter` related changes that you'd have to make - most important of which is the following line :-

```
<data android:scheme="content"/>
```

In addition to the changes in the `intent-filter`, I think you'd have to alter your code a bit to accept and work with a [content URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html), instead of a File URI. Something like this should do :-

```
Uri uriOfData = getIntent().getData();
    File file = null;
    String scheme = uriOfData.getScheme();
    String fileName = uriOfData.getEncodedPath();
    file = new File(filename);

    try {
        InputStream inputStream;
        if (file != null) inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        else inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uriOfData);
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: My java code is called only when I filter all metadatas "*/*". Otherwise file association doesn't work, and code is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Intent Filter has been changed From Nougat

So We can have different type and scheme

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    <data android:scheme="file" />
</intent-filter>
```

if u want to get text then you can go for **text/*** which means all text formate file

> Note: MIME type matching in the Android framework is case-sensitive,
>   unlike the formal RFC definitions. As a result, you should always
>   write these elements with lower case letters, or use
>   normalizeMimeType(String) to ensure that they are converted to lower
>   case.

```
 compileSdkVersion 25
 buildToolsVersion "25.3.1"
 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.example"
     minSdkVersion 16
     targetSdkVersion 25
     versionCode 1000
     versionName "3.0.6"
}
```

And also depend upon the Android build version you want target